# FOSElastica search in multiple entities

Tags: symfony, elastica, foselasticabundle

I managed to install FOSElastica in my symfony project, my fos_elsastica.yaml. It works fine with one entity.

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        user:
            persistence:
                driver: orm
                model: App\Entity\User
                provider: ~
                finder: ~
            properties:
                email: ~
```

Is it possible to search in multiples entities, like :

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
    indexes:
        user:
            persistence:
                driver: orm
                model: App\Entity\User
                provider: ~
                finder: ~
            properties:
                email: ~
        course:
            persistence:
                driver: orm
                model: App\Entity\Course
                provider: ~
                finder: ~
            properties:
                name: ~
```

If yes how to handle services.yaml file and controller function ? I need to be pointed in right direction.

I tried many things, without any success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the purpose is. There are multiple options for using the different indexes.

If you want to search in another index, you can use the IndexManager, for example:

```
services:
    app.elasticsearch_search:
        class: App\Service\ElasticsearchSearchService
        arguments:
            - '@fos_elastica.index'


<?php 

namespace App\Service;

use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Manager\IndexManager;

class ElasticsearchSearchService
{
    private $indexManager;

    public function __construct(IndexManager $indexManager)
    {
        $this->indexManager = $indexManager;
    }

    public function searchInIndex(string $index, string $query)
    {
        $index = $this->indexManager->getIndex($index);
        return $userIndex->search($query);
    }
}
```

But if you want to combine an index, take a look at nested objects: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/doc/indexes.md#nested-objects-in-foselasticabundle in the documentation. I'm not aware of your entity setup, but here's a small example with the same assumptions.

```
fos_elastica:
   clients:
       default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }
   indexes:
       course:
           use_alias: true
           properties:
               id: {type: integer}
               name: {type: text}
               user:
                   type: 'object'
                   properties:
                       id: {type: integer}
                       name: {type: text}
           persistence:
               driver: orm
               model: App\Entity\Course
               provider: ~
               finder: ~
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I want to be able to search string in an entity or another or another. Could you complete your answer and show me how i should write fos_elastica.yaml ? Thank you so much in advance.